# Flutter: How to start app when NFC tag connected

Tags: android, flutter, nfc

Is it possible to start flutter app when NFC is connected and then get data from NFC tag?

In Android manifest we need to define what activity NFC is starting, then when activity is loaded we get data from it. Problem is when I tried to transfer data to flutter side.

dataChannel.invokeMethod("_didRecieveScannedData", data)

I guess it doesn't get data because app is started from android side and flutter did not initialise MethodChannel.

Is there a way to start flutter side when NFC tag is connected?